# Pass Json file content in docker-compose.yml

Tags: json, linux, docker-compose, gcloud

I need to pass contents of JSON file as value of environment variable `USER_PASS` in `docker-compose.yml` file. The `docker-compose.yml` file looks like following:

```
  watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    environment:
      - REPO_USER=_json_key
      - REPO_PASS=?????
```

and Json file looks as follows:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  ....
}
```

I tried passing the Json text in many ways like surrounding it with single quotes, removing new line etc but nothing is working. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just removed all the spaces along with new line characters and it worked.